# Composite C1 admin system stuck on initializing, the site works fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c1-cms

My client just updated me that they are facing some issues with the CMS today so tried to login as admin however could not, it gives me the login page but then is stuck on initializing page.

### Versions

Composite C1 3.2 Build 3.2.4497.34793
.net 4.0
IIS 6.0 (I know old :) )

### Steps taken

- Restarted the site in IIS.
- Same issue on all the browsers.
- We have several sites built using Composite C1 the rest are working
  fine,    they are same version same build. In fact the preview
  version of this    same site works fine.

Similar issue reported [here](http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/353987) - However my build is already updated to the version informed here.

It would be great help if anyone has faced a similar issue and knows how to proceed with trouble shooting this issue.

Comment: Update - was able to login using credentials of an editor role. Looks like its related to this particular admin profile. Unfortunately cannot create another admin user as this is the only admin account I have (unfortunate huh). I am locked out of it.

Comment: The logged errors you have are likely happen on frontend part, and not helping much to gess what's wrong with the console. Try to use FireBugs or Chrome developer tools, to see what requests fail/what javascript errors occur while Console is starting up

Comment: Hi @Dmitry Dzygin. I agree those errors are irrelevant.

Comment: Just in case any one else encounters a similar issue, don't know if it will help but still.

I created a second copy of the site in IIS and copy of the live DB, tried logging into admin site of this copy and it worked. 

It was strange as I was expecting to reproduce the original issue but it dint, so pointed this copy IIS instance to the Live DB and again was able to login to the admin system without a problem.

So then tried logging in through to the live system and it worked.

Comment: So the conclusion is I don't really know how it got resolved whether pointing the copy IIS instance to the Live DB helped somehow but the issue got resolved.

I will monitoring the system and will update it here, if I find anything else that can be useful.

Comment: Removed the errors from the question as they were irrelevant to the issue.